# How to add keys to Redis using Lua and ServiceStack Redis

Tags: lua, redis

I'm using C# and the Redis client named ServiceStack Redis. I want to add keys to Redis using a Lua script. Currently I use a loop to test this but no keys are added. What am I doing wrong? See code below.

```
using (var redisClient = GetPooledRedisClient())
{
    StringBuilder luaScript = new StringBuilder();
    luaScript.AppendLine("for variable = 0, 10, 1 do");
    luaScript.AppendLine("  redis.call('SET', KEYS[variable], 'variable')");
    luaScript.AppendLine("end");

    var sha1 = redisClient.LoadLuaScript(luaScript.ToString());
    return redisClient.ExecLuaShaAsString(sha1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the value of `KEYS` table is not set; either the table is empty or its value is  `nil` and you get a run-time error. What sets the content of KEYS[variable]? What if you replace it with 'foo' (as in "redis.call('SET', 'foo', 'variable')")? Do you get the key 'foo' set?

According to this [Intro for Redis programmers](http://www.redisgreen.net/blog/2013/03/18/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/), you get KEYS populated when you run the script using `redis-cli` command (you pass the number of keys and then the keys themselves). Note that it's going to be a normal Lua table, so your loop should start from 1, not 0. If that's not your case, then you don't need to use the KEYS table and need to use a different table as KEYS won't be populated for you.

Comment: It Works with redis.call('SET', 'foo', 'variable'). But what I have read this way is not allowed. You must use the KEYS table. Do you know how to accomplish that?

Comment: Updated the answer with details on KEYS.